# Openstack via Landscape/Autopilot - "console is currently unavailable"

Tags: 14.04, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have just deployed a physical Openstack environment with the latest stable Openstack-Install script and then the Landscape autopilot, the install of both parts seems to have completed successful and I now have 3 servers resourcing my small cloud.

Logging in with the username and password specified works as expected and building new instances using the default `Ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudmg-amd64-disk1` also seems to work, judging by the log clip:

> Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 finished at Tue, 19 Jul 2016 16:56:51 +0000. Datasource DataSourceOpenStack [net,ver=2].  Up 202.90 seconds

However I am seeing an issue when I select the console:

[image]

I have tried building version 12 instances as well be the same result, have also cut new SSH keys via the Horizon console and rebuilt but with no luck! I'm not really sure where to start looking but have a feeling it will be something to do with KVM and not being called but that is just a guess. So any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer - Looks like for some reason the auto-pilot build script is not setup to enable and configure the console component via "VNC" so instead the end user has to connect to juju and push config to the cloud controllers and all nova endpoints.

Not sure if it should be logged as a bug or not but it will defiantly be putting people off taking up OpenStack.

Answer (score 0):

We don't enable the console because the security implications of doing so are horrendous.

The OpenStack Autopilot will deploy OpenStack in the best, safest way we know how and unfortunately that means no console access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand the comment about security being the issue, are you saying that OpenStack's chosen console access method/protocol when implemented via a private network and proxy setup is so insecure that it is better to break the OOB Access feature entirely with no "decent alerting to the fact" or true alternative ?

There are a significant number of public clouds out there running OpenStack who must have surmounted this "security" issue and that do offer console access so why is this fundamentally different ?

In honesty this is the first time i have used a VM command and control software implementation that has no console access out of the box AZUE, vCloud, Esx/vCenter, Hyper-v/SCVMM, KVM, Zen/Zenserver all do and not having it as ether a default or at least an easy to select option is going to turn a whole heap of people away before they start!

Even if there is massive push back to enable or offer this feature by default then having a big disclaimer as part of the published Guide or Landscape OS install along with "well" documented steps to enable/work-around would be better than an innocuous error that looks like something has broken during the install?

This still feels like a bug rather than something you would choose to do in a product/package aimed at getting people to pick up OpenStack.